# How do you interpret 'high risk eggs' in this context?

Tags: phrases, expressions, adjectives

I was watching a documentary about border control at an airport. One woman was carrying prohibited foods. The relevant part of the original sentence is as follows:

> This woman ... has been caught with fresh fruit and other prohibited food items including high risk eggs, but the bio officers ... [something about bio officers not understanding the woman's reaction].

How would you interpret the 'high risk egg' part?
A. the whole egg category is high-risk
B. it refers to a specific type of 'high-risk' eggs
C. either of the above

I am not searching for answers about import regulations. What I'm interested in is whether native speakers have a preferred interpretation for this sentence.

Unless the reading is related to prior knowledge -- would you have a different reading if it's not eggs? What if it's beef? Broccoli? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Given the very limited context, it's not possible to say with any certainty.

Comment: If you genuinely want an answer, it should be easy to find food import rules for the country under question. It's hard to see why some eggs should be high risk and others not (probably related to country of origin rather than type of egg, because different countries have different rules for egg production) but this is way outside the scope of English SE.

Comment: High-risk Foods - Raw or undercooked foods, e.g. meat, poultry, seafood and eggs, are high-risk foods, as there is no or inadequate heat treatment to eliminate the microorganisms present that can pose risks to human health. https://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/whatsnew/whatsnew_act/High_Risk_Food_high_risk_food.html#:~:text=Raw%20or%20undercooked%20foods%2C%20e.g.,pose%20risks%20to%20human%20health.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Stuart, but what I'm interested in is whether native speakers have a preferred interpretation for this sentence, not really about the rules. It doesn't have to be eggs -- unless you're saying the interpretation depends on the readers' knowledge about the product?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I've made my question clearer :)

Comment: Whether the premodifier is descriptive, speaking of a property of the whole set of eggs –  or identifying, pointing to some particularly risky subset – is unclear from the wording. Pragmatics (say the knowledge that archaeopteryx eggs are particularly dangerous and in the news) or context (a previous clear mention of the set or certain subsets) would give a default reading. But as it stands, it needs rewriting to disambiguate.

Comment: It's ambiguous enough that tone of voice, phrasing, and other nuances of speech would steer interpretation. If *high-risk* is said somewhat sarcastically, it would likely being interpreted as mocking a regulation we should presume exists. An ominous tone may imply a real danger. I suspect most people don't know import regulations enough to factor that in to their intuitions, so the best answer will be "it depends" or "there is no definitive answer", which here is often closed as matter-of-opinion.

Comment: Check the country in question. It sounds like a misnomer for: fresh eggs, as opposed to hard-boiled ones. People seem to forget that rules like this apply to/in countries and not "in English per se".

Comment: @Lambie the country is New Zealand. Does this context help in any way in this case?

Comment: Ok, well, it turns out that is a Tiktok video where writing is not exactly Nobel-prize quality and it concerns a woman bringing in eggs from China to I dunno-what-country.  So, it can be a misnomer OR just that eggs can be dangerous when uncooked...one would have to ask the Tiktok poster.

Comment: @Lambie the destination country is New Zealand. All countries on islands, big or small, have very strict rules about food items, plants, animals, etc.

Comment: It makes no difference because high risk eggs is not a "thing".

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is "whether native speakers have a preferred interpretation", then I understood "high risk eggs" in context to mean "eggs of a particular type which poses a high risk".

Comment: ...which only goes to show that there is no hard-and-fast interpretation.

Comment: ... and surely that the question is off-topic and should be closed rather than answered.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder whether there's a stronger preference now.

Comment: Sorry why is it off-topic? Isn't this an English-learning forum?

Comment: @SuperDuperMario No; that's [ELL.SE]

Comment: @SuperDuperMario But they won't have an answer either, for the same reason. It could go both ways.

Comment: Oh sorry! I misunderstood the purpose of this forum.

Comment: I think that's an answer itself. Thank you again!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since the answer would appear to be (C), the question is answerable.

Comment: But answers (a) and (b) have also already been offered by able Anglophones. Which answer is correct is thus up for debate.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is "whether native speakers have a preferred interpretation", then I understood "high risk eggs" in context to mean "eggs, which, as everyone knows, pose a high risk".

P.S.  I don't know if eggs can spread viral disease. A quick scan of NIH.gov suggested that they can make a person sick if the eggs have salmonella bacteria and are not properly cooked before being eaten, but I haven't found anything so far to indicate that the egg-in-shell is a transmission vector of any pathogen that can  quickly spread among a human population. Though perhaps there is some risk to endemic poultry.

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly I want. How would you describe a certain type of eggs that are high risk in this context if I may add a follow-up question?

Comment: How would I describe them or how would I refer to them?

Comment: How would you refer to them? Thanks!

Comment: I would use the phrase "certain high-risk eggs" if all I wanted to do was say that some kinds of eggs are risky while others are not, and hers were one of the risky kind.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!